# Can we overwrite scss variables based on data attributes?

Tags: html, sass, themes, scss-mixins, scss-functions

I am new to SCSS and writing a code for theming using SCSS, but stuck in the below code.

```
$themes: (
    light: (
        bg-color: #1ed760,
        text-color: black, 
    ),
    dark: (
        bg-color: black,
        text-color: white,
    )
);

$theme: light;

[data-theme="dark"] {
    $theme: dark;
}

[data-theme="light"] {
    $theme: light;
}

@function get-palette($key) {
    @return map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), $key)
}
```

Created a object as themes containing keys for theme and associated with colors.

---

**Now what I am doing is, trying to change the theme variable (`$theme`) according to the data attribute (`data-theme`) of the document**

```
<html data-theme="dark">
...
</html>
```

**And with the help of get-palette function getting the variable by $key associated to $theme, but the code not working as I wanted**

*If I am doing wrong please guide me how we can achieve this behavior using data-theme*

**NOTE: I am doing this all stuff in React.**

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const darkThemeButton = document.querySelector("[data-theme='dark']");
    const lightThemeButton = document.querySelector("[data-theme='light']");
    const body = document.body;

    darkThemeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
        applyTheme();
    });

    lightThemeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        body.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
        applyTheme();
    });

    // Function to apply the selected theme
    function applyTheme() {
        const theme = body.getAttribute("data-theme");
        if (theme === "dark") {
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg-color", "var(--dark-bg-color)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--text-color", "var(--dark-text-color)");
        } else {
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg-color", "var(--light-bg-color)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--text-color", "var(--light-text-color)");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
/* ------------------- *
   common variables
*-------------------- */
$--light-bg-color: #1ed760;
$--light-text-color: #000000;

$--dark-bg-color: #000000;
$--dark-text-color: #FFFFFF;

/* ------------------- *
   common light color 
*-------------------- */
:root {
    --bg-color: #{$--light-bg-color};
    --text-color: #{$--light-text-color};
}

/* ------------------- *
   common dark color 
*-------------------- */
[data-theme="dark"] {
    --bg-color: #{$--dark-bg-color};
    --text-color: #{$--dark-text-color};
}

// default color for light mode 
body {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Theming Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body id="body">
    <h1>Theming Example</h1>
    <p>Select a theme:</p>
    <button data-theme="dark">Dark Theme</button>
    <button data-theme="light">Light Theme</button>

   
</body>

</html>
```

I have a suggestion for this type of structure for your CSS code so I thought your code would work as well.

You have use of function in scss but it makes your code too complicated.
And you can have this structure in any framework and even normal HTML pages.